# Angular2 - make an array of radio buttons "required"

Tags: javascript, html, forms, angular, radio-group

I'm using template forms for Angular2 app and I'm using the `ngForm` to verify if the form is valid and all inputs have `required` tags, along with `ngModel`.

Everything was pretty straightforward but when I came across and array of values in form of radio buttons. I can't just `ngFor` the whole array and set every radio to `required`, this won't work. I could do some custom events and handle if the value is set, but I'd like to use that ngForm.form.valid feature.

So, here's my radio code:

```
<fieldset class="form-group">
    <legend>Rating system</legend>
    <div class="form-check" *ngFor="let rating of ratingSystem">
      <label class="form-check-label" (mouseenter)="currentRatingId = rating.id">
        <input 
          type="radio" 
          class="form-check-input" 
          name="ratingsRadio" 
          id="rating_{{rating.id}}" 
          value="{{rating.id}}" 
          [checked]="movie.rating.id === rating.id"
          (click)="movie.rating = rating" />
        {{rating.short_tag}}
      </label>
      <small [hidden]="currentRatingId !== rating.id">  &nbsp; &ndash; &nbsp; {{rating.description}}</small>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
```

And here's the button that submits the form:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!myForm.form.valid">Add movie</button>
```

Any ideas how to make the radio buttons "required" so that I can use the `form.valid` part? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I overthought this, it's pretty straightforward too.

```
<fieldset class="form-group">
    <legend>Rating system</legend>
    <div class="form-check" *ngFor="let rating of ratingSystem">
      <label class="form-check-label" (mouseenter)="currentRatingId = rating.id">
        <input 
          type="radio" 
          class="form-check-input" 
          name="ratingsRadio" 
          [value]="rating.id"
          [(ngModel)]="movie.rating.id"
          required
          />
        {{rating.short_tag}}
      </label>
      <small [hidden]="currentRatingId !== rating.id">  &nbsp; &ndash; &nbsp; {{rating.description}}</small>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
```

Comment: Where is the `ngModel`?? Also I'm not sure if there's a way do the validation (using template driven forms) on multiple `inputs` without some hack. See this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9615).

Comment: an other workaround if you want , that to make always the first radio of the list `checked` , so it is forced to be required since you cant uncheck it.

Comment: I think you would make your life a lot easier if you used reactive forms for this.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think this through. The `ngModel` part was missing and then everything worked as expected. I'll be looking into the reactive forms for sure. Thanks